# How can I select random element from the list?

Tags: java

I am using `java.util.LinkedList`

Is there any method that helps me with this?

Comment: `ArrayList` might be a better choice.  Getting a random element from a `LinkedList` is O(N) cost (because you have to traverse from the first element to the chosen element).  An `ArrayList` is O(1) to access a specific element.

Comment: Yeah.. my code now runs about 80% faster than before. Thanks!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 int len = list.size(); 
 Random randomGenerator = new Random();
 int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(len);
```

Comment: This just gets the a random index. Use `list.get(randomInt)` to get the actual value (as all the other answers have stated).

Comment: Agreed.  The question was select a random element though, so I stopped there.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4):

If you only need one element you can use the [Random](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class to generate a (pseudo) random value (as you wrote in your question):

```
E element = list.get(new Random().nextInt(list.size()));
```

*Remember `LinkedList.get(index)` is an O(n) operation, as noted in the comments it's better to use an `ArrayList` for this purpose.*

If you want to shuffle the whole array you can use the [Collections](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) api like this:

```
Collections.shuffle(list);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also shuffle the `List` using `Collections.shuffle` and pick the first element everytime though this might be a bit expensive computation wise. Just another trick you should be aware of. :-)

```
final List<String> lst = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
Collections.shuffle(lst);
final String rndStr = lst.get(0);
```

Comment: Although you can do this (and it's a useful technique if you need more than one element), it's quite expensive compared to just looking an element up.

Comment: Agreed, hence I've mentioned in my post that this technique is computationally expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Get the list length with `size()`, create a random number between 0 and size-1 and use `get(index)` to retrieve the element with that index.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need just one element, go with dacwe's solution. If you need several values (e.g. when simulating a card game, bingo etc.) you can use `java.util.Collections.shuffle(list);`, and call `list.remove(0);` for every element you need.